# How to go back to the previous screen instead of exiting the app on back key pressed

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

In my Android app when back key pressed the app closed. I want it to go back to the previous screen instead of exiting the app.

While I am using AS3, flash CS5.5.

So what is the code that does that.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intercept Hardware key, and perform your inner logic:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown, false, 0, true);

function onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent):void{
    //Back is 94, for Menu key, use 95
    if(e.keyCode == 94){
        //Stop default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
        //perform your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override onBackPressed method

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
       Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
       setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(setIntent);
    }
```